# Is 'this.' excessive for imported members within constructor?

Tags: typescript, angular5

In Angular2+ examples I often see that the imported modules passed within constructor as arguments are referenced by 'this.' notation. It does make a sense to me since they are members of the class and thus should be accessible through the 'self' of the class. So generally speaking the code looks something like this:

```
import { Component  } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeModule } from '@somewhere';

@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor( private _importedModule: SomeModule ) {
   this._importedModule.doesSmethingSpecial();
  }
}
```

However, in TypeScript examples I often see the 'self' reference being ommited. I mean something like this:

```
new_member_from_outside = is_something_external;

class SomeClass extends Something { 
        some_variable: some_type; 

        constructor( new_member_from_outside ) {
            this.some_variable = new_member_from_outside.doingSomethingSpecial();
        }
    }
```

Hence I started using it in my Angular2+ code like this:

```
import { Component  } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeModule } from '@somewhere';

@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor( private _importedModule: SomeModule ) {
   _importedModule.doesSomethingSpecial();
  }
}
```

The code works, no errors, no linter blood in my IDE, but reviewers of my code rewrite it to use 'this.' and comment that I do not use the scope properly. I wonder. Is my approach faulty? Is it bad manner? If yes, how exactly my approach mess up with the scope? I asked my reviewers and the answer was -> study the scope ( helpful :D ). From what I read I cannot really say that this is bad and how bad it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confused, and your revieers seem to be, too. First, the constructor arguments are not "imports". They're arguments.

If you have a constructor like this:

```
constructor(foo: string)
```

then `foo` is an argument, and only an argument. It's not a property of the object. So using `this.foo` would be an error. It's just a regular argument, visible only from inside the constructor (i.e. a local variable).

If you add a visibility modifier (private, protected, public) in front of the argument, then it *also* becomes a property. I.e. this code

```
constructor(private foo: string) {}
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
private foo: string;

constructor(private foo: string) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
```

So, inside such a constructor, `foo` is both a local variable, usable with `foo`, and a private property, usable with `this.foo`. Both variables refer to the same value, so using `foo.length` (for example) or `this.foo.length` is equivalent.

Comment: Oh, yeah, my vocabulary is not 100% sharp, I updated my question, so it is perhaps more comprehensible now.

Comment: Anyway, I get that I am not wrong and my code is valid. Thank you for clearing this up, I will sleep better now ;).